# Страница вверх после нажатия поля button type submit

Tags: html, javascript

Да ребят, такой вот вопрос, забыл совсем и по какому запросу гуглить не знаю даже.
Как избавиться от прыгающей вверх страницы после нажатия на кнопку, например

```
<button type="submit">просмотренно | скрыть</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Запоминайте куда-нибудь положение старницы по вертикали, например `$(window).scrollTop()` и после submit, например, на $(window).onload восстанавливайте скролл (что-то типа `window.scrollTo(x,y)`).

Comment: А как реализовать? Я, например, ничего умнее, чем запоминать положение скролла в куки, сделать не смог. Вот пример - http://jsfiddle.net/2mP5N/

Comment: @andreyqin, ну это зависит от конкретной задачи. можно и так.

Comment: А можно ли запомнить положение скролла, например, в переменной?

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы не прыгал контент может тогда лучше не перезагружать страницу а выполнять ajax запрос